# Alpinejs Accordion and Toggle on click

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I’m using Alpinejs and Tailwind.

I'm trying to create an accordion with a toggle on each tab, but I want that toggle to trigger at the same time as when a user clicks to open each part of the accordion... here's what I got so far:

```
  <ul class="block mb-4" x-data="{pay:null}">
    <li class="flex flex-col">
      <div @click="pay !== 'cc' ? pay = 'cc' : pay = null" class="cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 flex items-center bg-blue-50 border text-xl font-semibold border-blue-800 text-blue-800 inline-block hover:shadow rounded-t">
        <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-orange-500 bg-gray-200" x-data="{ on: false }" aria-pressed="false" :aria-pressed="on.toString()" @click="on = !on" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'bg-orange-500': on, 'bg-white': !(on) }">
          <span class="sr-only">Credit Card</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200 translate-x-0" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="ml-2">Credit / Debit Card</span>
      </div>
      <p x-show="pay == 'cc'" class="bg-white border-l border-r border-blue-800 py-4 px-2">
        This is made with Alpine JS and Tailwind CSS
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="flex align-center flex-col">
      <h4 @click="pay !== 1 ? pay = 1 : pay = null" class="cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-400 text-white text-center inline-block hover:opacity-75 hover:shadow hover:-mb-3">Accordion item 2</h4>
      <p x-show="pay == 1" class="border py-4 px-2">
        There's no external CSS or JS
      </p>
    </li>
    <li class="flex align-center flex-col">
      <h4 @click="pay !== 2 ? pay = 2 : pay = null" :class="{'cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-500 text-white text-center inline-block hover:opacity-75 hover:shadow hover:-mb-3': true, 'rounded-b': pay != 2}">Accordion item 3</h4>
      <p x-show="pay == 2" :class="{'border py-4 px-2': true, 'rounded-b': pay == 2}">
        Pretty cool huh?
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

https://codepen.io/kennyk3/pen/eYBwEXN

Comment: `but I want that toggle to trigger at the same time` could you please elaborate more on this.

Comment: When a user clicks to open the accordion with the toggle button on it, I want the toggle button to also change. So when the accordion is open, the toggle is "on". Right now it only works when you click directly on the toggle. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty green, so bear with me. I actually just want to comment but don't have enough reputation.

First of all, you need to remove `bg-gray-200` from your `<button class>` because you're binding `:class="{ bg-{color} }` for `on: true` and `on: false` states. Another one is `bg-orange-500` and `ring-orange-500` isn't a defined utility on Tailwind CSS. Maybe you mean `bg-yellow-500` and `ring-yellow-500`? Other than that, what is `x-state`? I can't find it in Alpine.js docs.

Okay, about your requested problem, your code actually has 2 issues.

1. You want a `parent` component to communicate with a `child` component, like a nested component. Alpine.js doesn't do that. Either you merge both components holding multiple properties in the `parent` component so that you only have one `x-data` or you `$dispatch('customEvent')` on your `<div>` at the `@click` event (together with `pay` toggling) and listen to the `@customEvent.window` on your `<button>` component.

Alternatively, you can install Alpine Magic Helpers for the `$component/$parent` communication or install Spruce for saving all states.

2. Because of your `<button>` is nested in your `<div>`, you're firing both `@click` events every time you `@click` the `<button>`. This is why your code looks like the `<button>` component communicates with your `<ul>` component which is untrue. You're firing two different `@click` events. Because of this behavior, if you `$dispatch('customEvent')` from your `<div>` component and listen to the `@customEvent.window` on your `<button>`, you'll end up toggling your `on` state twice. Try add `@click.debounce.250` on your `<button>` together with the `@customEvent.window` and you'll see it toggles to and fro.

As for that, you need to remove `@click` event on your `<button>` while listening to the `@customEvent.window` so that the toggling happens once, or better you merge both `x-data` making your `<ul>` holding multiple properties (no need to `$dispatch('customEvent')` on your `<div>` and `@click` on your `<button>`, just one `@click` on your `<div>`).

In my implementation, I make `x-data` to hold both:

```
<ul class="block mb-4" x-data="{pay:null, on: false}">
  <li class="flex flex-col">
    <div @click="pay !== 'cc' ? pay = 'cc' : pay = null, on = !on" class="cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 flex items-center bg-blue-50 border text-xl font-semibold border-blue-800 text-blue-800 inline-block hover:shadow rounded-t">
      <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-yellow-500" aria-pressed="false" :aria-pressed="on.toString()" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'bg-yellow-500': on, 'bg-gray-200': !(on) }">
        <span class="sr-only">Credit Card</span>
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200 translate-x-0" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }"></span>
      </button>
      <span class="ml-2">Credit / Debit Card</span>
    </div>
    <p x-show="pay == 'cc'" class="bg-white border-l border-r border-blue-800 py-4 px-2">
      This is made with Alpine JS and Tailwind CSS
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="flex align-center flex-col">
    <h4 @click="pay !== 1 ? pay = 1 : pay = null" class="cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-400 text-white text-center inline-block hover:opacity-75 hover:shadow hover:-mb-3">Accordion item 2</h4>
    <p x-show="pay == 1" class="border py-4 px-2">
      There's no external CSS or JS
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="flex align-center flex-col">
    <h4 @click="pay !== 2 ? pay = 2 : pay = null" :class="{'cursor-pointer px-5 py-3 bg-indigo-500 text-white text-center inline-block hover:opacity-75 hover:shadow hover:-mb-3': true, 'rounded-b': pay != 2}">Accordion item 3</h4>
    <p x-show="pay == 2" :class="{'border py-4 px-2': true, 'rounded-b': pay == 2}">
      Pretty cool huh?
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/wanahmadfiras/pen/jOVgBrz

Answer (score 0):

Accordions (among other components) are now part of official [AlpineJS documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/components). Use them for perfect out of the box accordions.